# mounting fuse gives invalid argument error in python

Tags: python, fuse

I have written python code to a mount fuse on a point mount. It always gives invalid argument error. I have tried the same program in C and it works fine. Can any of python Guru's help me out in finding what the problem is, I have pasted the code here.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import stat
import os
import ctypes
from ctypes.util import find_library

libc = ctypes.CDLL (find_library ("c"))

def fuse_mount_sys (mountpoint, fsname):
        fd = file.fileno (file ("/dev/fuse", 'w+'))
        if fd < 0:
                raise OSError("Could not open /dev/fuse")

        mnt_param = "%s,fd=%i,rootmode=%o,user_id=%i,group_id=%i" \
                        % ("allow_other,default_permissions,max_read=131072", \
                        fd, stat.S_IFDIR, os.getuid(), os.getgid())

        ret = libc.mount ("fuse", "/mount", "fuse", 0, mnt_param)
        if ret < 0:
                raise OSError("mount failed with code " + str(ret))
        return fd

fds = fuse_mount_sys ("/mount", "fuse")
```

mount syntax is:

```
int mount(const char *source, const char *target,
                 const char *filesystemtype, unsigned long mountflags,
                 const void *data);
```

I tried using swig and also writing the program using  in C and then creating a .so from it and they worked. But I am interested in writing in pure python. Thanks in advance.

output of strace:

```
$ strace -s 100 -v -e mount python fuse-mount.py 
mount("fuse", "/mount", "fuse", 0, "allow_other,default_permissions,max_read=131072,fd=3,rootmode=40000,user_id=0,group_id=0") = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)


$ strace -s 100 -v -e mount ./a.out 
mount("fuse", "/mount", "fuse", 0, "allow_other,default_permissions,max_read=131072,fd=3,rootmode=40000,user_id=0,group_id=0") = 0
```

Comment: It would be of great help if you could simplify programs presented in stackoverflow questions, to, say, less than 15 lines. You don't need any complicated error handling, `if fd < 0: raise ValueError('fileno failed')` is more than enough. Also, the `print`` calls don't particularly help and just obfuscate the real problem.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, I will take care next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ctypes.c_void_p`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_void_p) cannot be initialized with a string. Instead, just use a string without `c_void_p`.

You can then compare the output of

```
strace -v -e mount python mymount.py
```

and

```
strace -v -e mount ./mymount-c
```

until they match.

Also, make sure the file handle `fd` is still open when you call mount. `file("/dev/fuse", 'w+')` will be automatically garbage-collected and closed by some Python implementations, including cpython. You can prevent this by assigning the result of `file("/dev/fuse")` to a variable.

Comment: even with out c_void_p it gives the same error. Is the way I am passing parameters is wrong?

Comment: @hue You probably need to pass a slightly different format to fuse. Can you include the outputs of strace in your question?

Comment: @phihag I have updated the strace output. Do you need anything else?

Comment: @hue That's two outputs of the Python program, both the same. I meant one output of the Python program and one of the corresponding C program.

Comment: @hue Those two `mount` calls are identical, so you may wanna skip the `-e mount` and compare the syscalls before mount. I spotted a potential problem: You're not keeping the file handle around, allowing Python to close it.

Comment: @phihag: Thanks for identifying it, it is working now. How did you analyse that part, I would like to learn that.

Comment: @hue I looked over the code again; since both mount calls were identical, the difference must have been in the build-up. You couldv'e spotted it in the full strace output; it will contain a `close` shortly before the `mount`. Spotting errors in code becomes easier if all the error handling is trivial; it's more pythonic to just raise an exception anyways.